# The virtual machine could not be started because a required feature is not installed

Tags: docker, containers

I created image and container, trying the START the container and it throws the following error:

> Error response from daemon: hcsshim::CreateComputeSystem 8459c6c816e764642634ce29cfee666d30834df0f2792fba9e411d11bd0c33f6: The virtual machine could not be started because a required feature is not installed

I'm using Windows VM with the following configuration:

[image: VM configuration]

Answer (score 9):

You have to activate virtualization on your machine. Check if you have activated virtualization in BIOS, if yes, you have to activate the Hyper-V and container support.

Start Windows Powershell as Administrator and run these commands to activate the feautres.

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName containers –All
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V –All
```

You have to restart your computer after running these commands.

For further information: https://windowsreport.com/hyper-v-and-containers-not-enabled/

Comment: The 2nd part I did already, but 1st part to activate the vistualization in BIOS, I don't know how I can boot into BIOS in a VM?

Comment: Do you use VMWare or Virtualbox as virtualization software ?

Comment: I can see Oracle VM Virtual box.

Comment: I dont know if it is your problem but you have to enable nested virtualization in Virutalbox Manager. You can do it per Virtualbox GUI by going in your virutal machine settings or if the option is greyed out you can try per command line like -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54251855/virtualbox-enable-nested-vtx-amd-v-greyed-out

Comment: Running the following command in powershell made it working for me

DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /All /FeatureName:Microsoft-Hyper-V

Answer (score 1):

Was getting the same error; it turned out in my docker compose file the isolation setting for Traefik was set to **hyperv** changing it to **process** resolved it for me.