# Unable to open Docker Desktop on Ubuntu running on VMWare

Tags: docker, ubuntu, vmware

[Dialog shows when open Docker Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3unYu.png)
The dialog shows:
`running VM: running VM and dependencies: running VM: running qemu: qemu: waiting for qemu process: exit status 1`
I have tried to remove and reinstall the Docker Desktop and even the Ubuntu but it doesn't work.

Comment: Docker Desktop runs a hidden Linux virtual machine, even if you're running it on a native Linux host.  You don't really want to run a VM inside a VM.  Install the Docker Engine directly on the VM, don't try to use Docker Desktop here.

Comment: Hey @Hai, I got the same issue in my ubuntu 22.04. I am using Lenovo ThinkPad E14. Check your system bios info,  some times virtualization is disabled. Enable it from bios menu and after a reboot it will work as expected.   Just as a reference go through this comment https://github.com/docker/desktop-linux/issues/52#issuecomment-1205003720

Answer (score 0):

I was receiving the same error. I sort of fixed it. (It's slow)

I wanted to run Docker-Desktop on an Ubuntu 22.04 Virtual Machine (Client) on Virtual Box on Ubuntu Host.

I enabled these settings:

[Virtual Box Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJWfb.png)

Choose your virtual machine

Under System > Processor > Extended Features

- Enable PAE/NX
- Enable Nested VT-x/AMD-V

The second option is greyed out, so I had to follow this

[Virtualbox enable nested vtx/amd-v greyed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54251855/virtualbox-enable-nested-vtx-amd-v-greyed-out)

Restart everything.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue that was resolved by enabling intel's virtualization features in bios. It then runs normally.